# I have a problem with reaching the required result using Taylor Expansions.

Tags: taylor-expansion

[image]

I do not know how to get the result in the rhs. I know a few things about Taylor Expansions but I do not know how to get the extra term. I would really appreciate if someone could show me a step-by-step method on how to get to the result in the RHS.

Thank you!

Comment: What are $r$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: interest rates and volatility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is $u=\sqrt{\Delta t}$, and the expression can be re-written as
$$\mathrm e^{\bigl(r-\tfrac{\sigma^2}2\bigr)u^2+\sigma u}.$$
Taylor's expansion at order $2$ of $\mathrm e^x$ is $\;1+x+\dfrac{x^2}2+o(x^2)$, so we substitute $\bigl(r-\tfrac{\sigma^2}2\bigr)u^2+\sigma u$ to $x$ in this formula
$$\Bigl[\Bigl(r-\frac{\sigma^2}2\Bigr)u^2+\sigma u\Bigr]^2=\Bigl(r-\frac{\sigma^2}2\Bigr)^{\!2}u^4+2\sigma\Bigl(r-\frac{\sigma^2}2\Bigr)u^3+\sigma^2 u^2=\sigma^2 u^2+o(u^2).$$
So we obtain
$$1+\Bigl(r-\frac{\sigma^2}2\Bigr)u^2+\sigma u+\frac12\sigma^2 u^2+o(u^2)=1+\sigma u+ru^2+o(u^2).$$

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for